# How to run XCTest without running the app?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

When I try to run test cases in XCTest, I noticed that XCode will always active the app first. 
Since my app runs a lot of stuff during initialization (ex: checking new versions), I don't want it to run when I am debugging the test case.

Is there a way to run XCTest without activating the app?

Answer (score -2):

In the Xcode Menu *Test* under *Product*.This will run the tests only.

Comment: I tried this, but the app still starts before testing begins. I tried to create another empty app, but the problem still persists.